# Does multiclassing have an effect on exp/levelling up?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, experience-points, character-advancement

My understanding of the multiclassing system is a little vague, so I wanted to clarify. If I was to use multiclassing to level up, and increase my overall level, how does the exp get dispersed between the classes? For example, If I was say, a level 3 fighter, then I took on another class, this would bring my overall level to 4.

Does each class work individually in terms of exp? I.e. I might need 3000 exp to level up from level 3, but only 1000 exp to level up from level 1.

Or does it work in an overall sense? A level 3 Character (multiclass or not) requires 3000 exp to level up to level 4, and can then choose what to spend the level up on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's all the same.

> The experience point cost to gain a level is always based on your total character level, as shown in the Character Advancement table in chapter 1, not your level in a particular class. (*PHB*, p. 163, "Multiclassing: Experience Points")

The amount of XP you need to go from Fighter 3 to Fighter 4 is the same amount of XP you need to go from Fighter 3 to Fighter 3/Druid 1: 1800 xp.

See the "Character Advancement" table (as referenced in the quote above) on page 15 of the *Player's Handbook*. And when you read it, note that the XP numbers listed are *total* XP, not how much more you need on top of your existing XP to get to that level. So 3rd level to 4th is 2700 − 900 = 1800 more XP, not 2700 more XP.